# Definable sets in $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$

Tags: model-theory

I want to proove that set of all odd numbers is definable in $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$.

I am thinking about next formula
$$
\varphi{(y)} \equiv \exists x \;(x + x + 1 = y) 
$$
I think $1$ is not definable element in $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. So, I don't know how to solve the problem.

The same thing is with the set whose numbers are of the form $4k+2$ and $6k+3$.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For odd numbers: How about trying to define the even numbers, and then negate the formula?

For $4k+2$: Numbers that are not divisible by $4$ but are even.

For $6k+3$: Numbers that are not divisible by $6$ but are divisible by $3$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you mean.

Comment: @StepanMilosevic I noticed that you have not accepted answers to any of your questions. If this answer resolves your question, you can accept it by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.